# .NET Core + Docker Alpine + JsReport Local: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, .net-core, alpine-linux, jsreport

I'm trying to run JsReport with .NET Core on a Docker Alpine image.

I think that the problem is related to that "hack"

https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local#docker

Can someone help me translate that to Alpine commands ?

Follow my current configuration and stacktrace.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddJsReport(new LocalReporting()
                    .UseBinary(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ?
                                        jsreport.Binary.JsReportBinary.GetBinary() :
                                        jsreport.Binary.Linux.JsReportBinary.GetBinary())
                    .KillRunningJsReportProcesses()
                    .AsUtility()
                    .Create());
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet("generate/{uid}"), Route("generate")]
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public IActionResult GenerateReport([FromQuery] Guid uid)
{
   ReportResponseModel model = _reportHelper.Get(uid);

   HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
   .Configure(c => c.Template.Chrome = new Chrome
   {
      Landscape = model.Landscape
   });

   return View(model.ViewName, model.ViewModel);
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine AS base
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
RUN apk add --update tzdata
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Stacktrace

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at jsreport.Local.Internal.BinaryProcess.InnerExecute(String cmd, Boolean waitForExit)
at jsreport.Local.Internal.BinaryProcess.ExecuteExe(String cmd, Boolean waitForExit)
at jsreport.Local.Internal.LocalUtilityReportingService.RenderAsync(String requestString, CancellationToken ct)
at jsreport.AspNetCore.JsReportMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
 End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [jsreport.Binary.Linux](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jsreport.Binary.Linux) holds [jsreport binary](https://jsreport.net/learn/single-file-executable) that isn't compiled on alpine. Maybe it is just missing some dependencies causing `No such file or directory`, but I wasn't able to find out which. Probably, we would need to recompile the binary on alpine and embed it to another `jsreport.Binary.Linux.Alpine` nuget.

Could you consider running a full jsreport in another container and use for example docker-compose to link containers together. Here is a demo
https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-dotnet-example-docker-compose